# rank of the matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So I have matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, I should proof these two inequalities: $rank(AB) \leq \max(rank(A),rank(B))$ and $rank(AB) \leq \min(rank(A),rank(B))$.

So I understand that $A: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\max(rank(A)) \leq \max(\dim(Im(A))) = n$ and $B: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\max(rank(B)) \leq \max(\dim(Im(B))) = k$ and $\min(rank(A)) = \min(rank(B)) = \min (rank(AB)) = 0$.

But what after?

Comment: What does rank$(A,B)$ mean?

Comment: @JoseBrox $rank(A)$ and $rank(B)$

Comment: A suggestion: In order to get people interested in answering your questions, it is best if you stick to usual conventions! Otherwise they can read your statement and don't bother to try and understand it...

Comment: @JoseBrox You are right, this is my mistake, I'll fix it now)

Comment: Ok! Now, what do max$($rank$(A))$ and max$(\dim(Im(A)))$ mean?

Comment: @JoseBrox so $\max(rank(A))$ -- maximum possible rank of matrix $A$, $\max(dim(Im(A)))$ --  maximum dimension of the image of a linear map corresponding to matrix $A$, $Im(A) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$


may be I am incerrect writing $Im(A)$ and I should use $ImA$?

Comment: You mean the maximum rank when $A$ ranges in all $m\times n$ matrices? That's min$(m,n)$, since the rank is the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in the column or row space

Comment: @JoseBrox I think that this is equal to $\max \dim (ImA)$, no?

Comment: @vermator okey, thx, I will read it